# Adding Bootstrap CDN in index.html page causing menu to disappear in Ionic

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

When I add Bootstrap URL in index.html, my menu items tend to disappear, may be their color has changed.

Below is the image of menu on `home.html` before the URL is added:

[image]

Once I add this line of code in `index.html` , menu goes blank

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

See below image:

[image]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use bootstrap-saas. I believe some of Ionic css class has the same name in bootstrap which results in this conflict.

## Install Bootstrap SASS

#### version 3.x

```
npm install bootstrap-sass --save
```

#### version 4.x

```
npm install bootstrap@next --save
```

## Configuring Project

Create an empty file _variables.scss in **src/theme/**.
If you are using bootstrap-sass (I mean the 3rd version), add the following to `_variables.scss`:

```
$icon-font-path: '../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/';
```

In **src/theme/variables.scss** add the following at the beginning of your file:

#### version 3

```
@import 'variables';
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap';
```

#### version 4

```
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

For more information I found [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@hamidihamza/theming-your-angular-application-with-bootstrap-sass-79b4127fce61) about bootstrap-sass in angular

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap sets de the defaul text color in Ionic to white. If you change the background color or overwrite the text color you will see your menu items